# How to determine if the selected file in a FileChooser dosen't equal to the list of the Extensions? javafx

Tags: javafx, filechooser

i'm writing a program that manage the photos and there is a button that open a file chooser this program allow just the files with extension `*.png` so iwant to determine if the selected file is not with extension`*.png` do something. How i can do so and thanks very much

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want the user to be able to select other file types? If not, just use an [`ExtensionFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.ExtensionFilter.html).

Comment: yes the user can't open selected file with an other extension just with "*.png"

Comment: Isn't it the same question as this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/31099524/4170073

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX 2.2 Get selected file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637865/javafx-2-2-get-selected-file-extension)

Comment: So then what are you asking? If the user cannot select a file that doesn't have the .png extension, then if a file is selected it must have the .png extension. What is there to determine?